# Why Array / Dict / Optional are not compound types in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, compound-type

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/tuple-type) :

> In addition to user-defined named types, the Swift standard library defines many commonly used named types, including those that represent arrays, dictionaries, and optional values.
>
> [...]
>
> There are two compound types: function types and tuple types.

Well... It seems clear that dictionaries, arrays and optionals are named types and not compound types.

I don't understand why they are not compound types while tuple and function types are. Because from my perspective **all these types are host for other types**.

So two solutions :

- There's something about compound types I don't understand
- There's something about tuple and function types that I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly states that compound types are those which don't have a name. A tuple type and function types don't have names i.e when specifying these types in function signature or variable you don't say `let a : Tuple` or `let f : function`, instead you have to use their own specific notation to specify the types - `let a: (Int, Int)` or `let f: (Int, Int) -> Int`

Compound types doesn't have anything to do with "host for other types".

Comment: "A compound type may contain named types and other compound types." Also, your distinction about names is hazy -- functions and tuples do have names that act as typealiases. I don't think this sufficiently answers the question.

Comment: @sdasdadas Every type has 1) Its definition and 2) Optionally a name. A tuple doesn't have a name and you have to use its definition and same for function. Type aliases are different then the idea of name of a type.

Comment: Right, that's fine for a distinction. But the OP is asking _why_ this is the way it is.

Comment: Makes sense thanks. I think the word compound is therefore misleading.